# Issue in merging two array with same index

Tags: php

I have to merge below two array but I am facing issue in coding it. Please help.

```
array1 = array (
    [0] =>  "test",
    [1] =>  "test1",
    [2] =>  "test2" 
);


array2 = array(
    [0] => "test2",
    [1] => "test",
    [2] => "test1",
    [3] =>  "test3"         
)
```

expected array is

```
array(
    [0] => "test",
    [1] =>  "test1",
    [2] =>  "test2",
    [3] =>  "test3" 
)
```

Comment: See array_merge in the PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: And then see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: `@Aniket Shinde` check answers and if they are useful then try to mrak and up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Like you can read in the comments you should use `array_merge` to build the sum of both arrays. And then use `array_unique` to replace the dublicate entries.

```
$array1 = array (
    0 =>  "test",
    1 =>  "test1",
    2 =>  "test2" 
);

$array2 = array(
    0 => "test2",
    1 => "test",
    2 => "test1",
    3 =>  "test3"         
);

$out = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($out);
echo "</pre>";
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => test1
    [2] => test2
    [6] => test3
)
```

if you want to have clean indexes you can use `array_values` to reindex your array:

```
$out = array_values(array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2)));
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => test1
    [2] => test2
    [3] => test3
)
```